# node:events:304 Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000

Tags: node.js, server, port, nodemon, concurrently

I tried to use concurrently to run sever and client at the same time, then I got this error, even though I have tried lots of solutions online,  checked that no 5000 ports running, deleted modules, yarn.lock, cleaned up cache, restarted my PC, etc., the error stills remains.

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JT3gr.png)

```
{
  "name": "SPACEX_LAUNCH_STATS",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "App that lists SpaceX launch missions",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "yarn start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"yarn run server\" \"yarn run client\""
  },
  "author": "admin",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "concurrently": "^6.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-graphql": "^0.12.0",
    "graphql": "^15.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WL2U2.png)

```
Temps-MacBook-Pro:SPACEX_LAUNCH_STATS tempuser$ yarn run dev
yarn run v1.22.10
warning ../../../../package.json: No license field
$ concurrently "yarn run server" "yarn run client"
warning ../../../../package.json: No license field
warning ../../../../package.json: No license field
$ yarn start --prefix client
$ nodemon server.js
warning ../../../../package.json: No license field
[0] [nodemon] 2.0.9
[0] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[0] [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[0] [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[0] [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
$ node server.js --prefix client
[0] Server started on port 5000
[1] node:events:304
[1]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[1]       ^
[1] 
[1] Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000
[1]     at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1286:16)
[1]     at listenInCluster (node:net:1334:12)
[1]     at Server.listen (node:net:1420:7)
[1]     at Function.listen (/Users/tempuser/Documents/React/spaceX/SPACEX_LAUNCH_STATS/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
[1]     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/tempuser/Documents/React/spaceX/SPACEX_LAUNCH_STATS/server.js:17:5)
[1]     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1083:30)
[1]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1112:10)
[1]     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:948:32)
[1]     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:789:14)
[1]     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:72:12)
[1] Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
[1]     at emitErrorNT (node:net:1313:8)
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:80:21) {
[1]   code: 'EADDRINUSE',
[1]   errno: -48,
[1]   syscall: 'listen',
[1]   address: '::',
[1]   port: 5000
[1] }
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
[1] yarn run client exited with code 1
```

One thing suspicious is that i was able to kill all the ports but there's one is not killable. It says "No such process". I'm not sure if this is the running port hidden somewhere behind the scene. Here are the screenshots. Please help.

[No such process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOnJX.png)

Comment: Nobody likes looking at pictures of code. Please copy and paste you code onto this post.

Comment: You are calling same script(server.js) with concurrency which means it will try to use the same port. Can you tell what `yarn client` is for? concurrency can be achieved if you run the scripts on different ports and in separate context.

Comment: Nobody can say for sure unless you show some code, but it seems, that your `server.js` tries to create to listeners for port 5000 when you start it with the `--client` flag

Comment: @code added. @Apoorva Chikara @derpischer `yarn client` is used to start the frontend server of react-app. I tried deleting the "duplicate" scripts containing 'server.js' separately and then ran it, but the error message was still there.

Answer (score 0):

I changed   `"dev": "concurrently \"yarn run server\" \"yarn run client\""` to     `"dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""`, and everything runs fine now. I don't know why, but ports 3000 and 5000 can both run now